# Is there a way to prevent Neovim from editing another file?

Tags: neovim, filesystem

When I'm using Neovim in conjunction to [firenvim](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim) to edit a text box in the browser, I typically have the need to open another file.

I'd like to disable Neovim's ability to read from and write to other files besides the one in the current buffer.

This is to be used in conjunction with some other settings and features of firenvim in order to lock down Neovim inside the browser for security.

Is there a way to block Neovim from opening another file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can close all the holes, but I'd probably start with something like:

```
augroup test | au!
    autocmd BufLeave * throw 'Not allowed!'
augroup end
```

No doubt, you also should at least have `:set secure`.

Comment: Wouldn't the `autocmd` effectively disallow any exiting when used? I don't want to open another file but still want to be able to quit the current buffer.

Comment: @JohnZhau As usual, read `:h BufLeave`.